# Improving compute performance of Spark ML ALS

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I have a spark job that performs [Alternating Least Squares (ALS)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/ml-collaborative-filtering.html) on an implicit feedback ratings matrix. I create the ALS object as follows.

```
val als = new ALS()
  .setCheckpointInterval(5)
  .setRank(150)
  .setAlpha(30.0)
  .setMaxIter(25)
  .setRegParam(0.001)
  .setUserCol("userId")
  .setItemCol("itemId")
  .setRatingCol("rating")
  .setImplicitPrefs(true)
  .setIntermediateStorageLevel("MEMORY_ONLY")
  .setFinalStorageLevel("MEMORY_ONLY")
```

The ratings matrix is created and used to fit the ALS model as follows.

```
val ratingsSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("userId", IntegerType, nullable = true), 
  StructField("itemId", IntegerType, nullable = true),
  StructField("rating", DoubleType, nullable = true)))

val ratings = spark
  .read
  .format("parquet")
  .schema(ratingsSchema)
  .load("/ratings")
  .cache()

val model = als.fit(ratings)
```

There are roughly 150 million unique users and 1 million items in the `ratings` DataFrame, which has around 850 million rows.

Based on the numbers above, the ratings DataFrame should occupy ~20 GB space in memory when fully loaded. The userFactors DataFrame would be 150 MM x 150 doubles = 180 GB (roughly). The itemFactors DataFrame should be only 1.2GB.

It is taking a really long time for the job to complete (15+ hours). My cluster specs are as follows.

```
Provider: AWS EMR version 5.14.0
Spark version: 2.3.0
Cluster:
  1 MASTER node: m4.xlarge (8 cores, 16GB mem, 32GB storage)
  2 CORE nodes: i3.xlarge (4 cores, 30GB mem, 950 GB storage)
  20 TASK nodes: r4.4xlarge (16 cores, 122GB mem, 32 GB storage)
  Total TASK cores = 320
  Total TASK memory: 2440 GB
```

Based on the numbers above, all DFs should easily fit in memory (there is also TB+ HDFS available, if needed).

Job configuration:

```
--executor-memory 102g 
--num-executors 20 
--executor-cores 15
```

I can see that there are 20 executors running (and a driver too). I have tried caching the ratings DF and also without caching.

How do I tune the system to make it run faster, if possible?

Does anyone have insights into the [ALS job](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala)? Does it do a lot of shuffling? How can we minimize the shuffle?

The ratings matrix is in `parquet` format with 200 files stored in a bucket in S3.

Would it work better if I have lots of small instances (say 50) or should I get a few (say, 5) very big instances like r4.16xlarge (64 cores, 488GB mem)?

Comment: It is really hard to answer this question fully. I try to give you some questions which might help you in debugging. Have you checked the spark interface while your job was running? Can you see that the executors are used with their full capacity? Also which tasks are slow? Do you maybe see unequal distribution of the data to the executor nodes? Skewed partitions in the parquet files maybe?

Comment: The data is not exactly uniformly distributed in parquet files, but it's not very skewed either. How do I check that the executors are used to their full capacity? I see there were 20 executors, with memory which wasn't really used. Is there a way to check how much max memory tasks consume?

Comment: @Nik - did you find a solution for this?